# Loading javascript into wordpress wp_enqueue_script() problem

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to get my custom javascript (jQuery) to load correctly in Wordpress.
I know you have to use wp_enqueue_script() to do this correctly. However the problem I have is that the result is not my script, but in the place I should have javascript I have the code for a 404 page !
I've tried two ways of enqueueing the script :

```
wp_enqueue_script('sitescript', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/javascript/sitescript.js', array('jquery'),1);
```

just above wp_head()
and :`function my_script_load() {
    wp_enqueue_script('sitescript', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/javascript/sitescript.js', array('jquery'),null);
}
add_action('init', 'my_script_load');`

in functions.php

both methods have the same effect. When I inspect the HTML in firebug I find the script is corredtly referenced :

```
<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/doric2011/javascript/sitescript.js" type="text/javascript">
```

however when I inspect the script itself I find the following (an extract) :`



Page not found | Nick Kai Nielsen

and so on... It is a HTML output for a 404 page, but occupying a space where javascript should be...
Needless to say the script does not work.

I have only had this problem since updating to 3.1 and it does the same thing if I try loading highslide.js and highslide.config.js (professionally written scripts). The script I wish to load is already working on my site and I want to go on using it in the new theme I am developing.

has anyone any idea of what is happening ? And, of course, what should I do about it ?

This is a local installation - I'm not risking breaking my site until this is sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
add_action('init', 'my_script_load');
function my_script_load() {
wp_register_script('sitescript', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/javascript/sitescript.js', array('jquery'), true);
wp_enqueue_script('sitescript');
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your javascript file is in the proper location (and the URL isn't pointing to a spot where the JS file *isn't*...) try this:

```
function add_my_scripts() {
   $templatedir = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
   if(!is_admin()) {
      wp_register_script( 'sitescript', $templatedir . '/javascript/sitescript.js');
      wp_enqueue_script( 'sitescript' );
   }
 }

 add_action( 'init', 'add_my_scripts');
```

Comment: I've god a red face and egg on it ! There was a typo in the address for the script... a whole day wasted ugh ! Only lesson - I know what a badly addressed script gives in firebug !

Comment: LOL - happens to the best of us!